# Access to Raphael svg html tag

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, svg, raphael

I have a Raphael canvas. I don't know the size it will have (my elements are drawn by a loop). So I would like to know how to set up canvas size dynamicly. Knowing that i am working on IE8 and firefox.

My first idea was to give the canvas a size big enough to contain all the elements, and then reduce the size of the div containing the canvas himself. But after few tries, I can't get that working.... So I am know trying to access the html tag of the canvas to edit his size after the drawing with a litlle javascript code and i would like to know if it is possible and how ? 
Thx

Comment: Not quite sure if what you are suggesting seems like a good idea, it may, but wouldn't you rather have a fixed sized canvas, and let the svg be responsive and autoscale inside it ?

Comment: elements drawn have a dynamic size so it's pretty difficult to set a fixed canvas unless it is big enough to suppress risks (for now mine is a 100000px square...)

Comment: I would include a jsfiddle showing what you have so far to help others understand.

Comment: I changed my technique, I check the max size of the elements that will be draw and so i can set the width of my canvas, for the height i take a size huge enough. I don't think i can show you a jsfiddle all my code is running with a 2000 lines csv file to simulate a DB x)